# Cross-browser Javascript Function Scope Issue

Tags: javascript, function, scope

The following javascript works in Chrome and IE but errors out in Firefox because bar is undefined when assigned to callBar.

So who got their scope rules right?

```
function foo() {

    var callBar = bar;

    if (1 === 1) {
       callBar();
       function bar() {
          alert('yo');
       }
    }
}

foo();
```

Comment: Though it's an interesting brain teaser, do you really have some code like this? Functions (should) get hoisted and therefore defining them conditionally doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure who got it "right" according to the ECMA spec, but it doesn't really matter since you can't do this in all browsers and have to change your code :)

The simple explanation is that `function`s in `if` statement's aren't technically allowed and browsers do weird things with them.  Some browsers treat this as an expression, others as a declaration.  FF apparently treats it as an expression meaning it doesn't exist until the code gets to that point.  A detailed write-up is available at http://kangax.github.com/nfe/